# Getting an error in the pandas 10 minutes intro

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to get into pandas, and their 10 minutes intro ( http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html ) and ipythons help? function seems like a good place to get started.

However right at the start i ran into an error, where I either am totally oblivious to some basic concepts, or maybe have a broken or wrong install?

Right in the **Object Creation** section, there is the following example:

```
In [10]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1.,
   ....:                      'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
   ....:                      'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
   ....:                      'D' : np.array([3] * 4,dtype='int32'),
   ....:                      'E' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"]),
   ....:                      'F' : 'foo' })
   ....:
```

which - for me - results in

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-06146f407c7a> in <module>()
      3                               'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
      4                               'D' : np.array([3] * 4,dtype='int32'),
----> 5                               'E' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"]),
      6                               'F' : 'foo'})

TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

OK, yes, I am missing an argument, but where? I didn't do any **init**, but I suppose its somewhere in the various built in functions I use, probably the pd.Categorical?

The stuff with this error message I found so far, only shows examples where **init** explicitly gets used, and thus can be "found&fixed". And I also cant find any reports about such an error in the pandas intro, which I would suppose would be easy to find, if it would offer an erroneous example.

Comment: what version pandas, python and numpy are you using? This works for me on pandas 0.15.1, python 3.3.5 64-bit numpy 1.9.1

Comment: Works fine for me also, Python 3.4.2 64bit, pandas 0.15.0, numpy 1.9.0.

Comment: If the problem is with `pd.Categorical`, try just that line, categorical was introduced in 0.15.0 I think or maybe 0.14.1 so I think you probably need to upgrade your pandas

Comment: I am on python 2.7.5 and python-pandas 0.10.0, both installed via fedoras package manager.

Comment: Hm, OK, but i get info with 
    pd.Categorical?
I will try around and report back.

Comment: OK, it seems indeed to be pd.Categorical. When tried alone, it results in the previous error.  
And when I try the above code without the pd.Categorical line, it does work.  
So I guess I am indeed on the wrong version for this tutorial, but 0.10 is the most recent one I can find with fedora. So I guess I have to skip that step, and wait till fedora upgrades to 0.15?

Comment: The [installation docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) have instructions on how to compile pandas from source. Then you could always have the latest version of pandas. You might also want to use virtualenv, so you can install pandas as a normal user (with no risk of messing with system files).

Comment: switching to `Continuum Analytics` `anaconda` may be a good idea, too. `anaconda` is free and comes with a basic numpy-scipy stack and tons of scientific packages.